# SELECT query with exclusions specified in other table - 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Background:**

Table A has columns `userid`, `friend_id`. It stores all `friend_id`s of user having `userid`.

e.g. Table A

```
-----------------------
| userid | friend_id  |
|---------------------|
| 3      |    5       |
| 3      |    6       |
| 3      |    7       |
| 3      |    8       |
| 3      |    9       |
-----------------------
```

Table B has columns `blocker_userid`, `blocked_userid`

e.g. Table B

```
-------------------------------------
| blocker_userid | blocked_userid   |
|-----------------------------------|
|       6        |      3           |
|       9        |      3           |
-------------------------------------
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to get from table A friends list for given `userid`, except those friends who have blocked the `userid`. In case of above example, the query should return all `friend_id`s from table A for `userid` 3 except 6 and 9 (because they have blocked `userid` 3)

Can someone please tell how this can be done with ***single SELECT query***?

**Current Solution:**

Currently I am firing multiple queries. One to get all `friend_id`s for given `userid`. And then query to table B with each `friend_id` to find if they have blocked the `userid`. This approach is not at all efficient.

**Update:**

wewesthemenace's solution below works perfect here. However, in case if we want to *not* to get *"those who have blocked `userid` as well as those who have been blocked by `userid`"* then here is solution (By Hanno Binder who has answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429375/select-query-with-exclusions-specified-in-other-table-2))

```
SELECT f.*
FROM friends f
LEFT OUTER JOIN blocks b1
    ON b1.blocker_userid = f.friend_id AND b1.blocked_userid = f.userid -- userid blocked by friend
LEFT OUTER JOIN blocks b2
    ON b2.blocker_userid = f.userid AND b2.blocked_userid = f.friend_id -- friend blocked by userid
WHERE b1.blocker_userid IS NULL
AND b2.blocker_userid IS NULL
```

Comment: [sql-server] & [mysql]? choose one or tag with [sql] for a generic sql solution. Also, does `friend_name` really need to be in `TableA`, surely that should be looked up based on `friend_id`.

Comment: Removed wrong tag. I am doing it in [mysql]. Yes, `friend_name` because am looking for something like `select friend_name from A where...`

Comment: I agree with @Tanner here. You should have a table i.e. `user` with `userid`,`name` as columns.

Comment: I got the point. Edited accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE
    a.userid = @userid
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE
            b.blocked_userid = a.userid
            AND b.blocker_userid = a.friend_id
    )
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4669d/1/0)

---

Using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON b.blocked_userid = a.userid
    AND b.blocker_userid = a.friend_id
WHERE
    a.userid = @userid
    AND b.blocked_userid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Select inside select would have [performance penalty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389563/query-performance-query-on-multiple-tables-vs-composite-query) in `mysql`? Can this be done using joins?

Answer (score 1):

```
select friend_id,friend_name from tableA a 
Left Join tableB b on a.friend_id=b.blocker_userid and b.blocked_userid = @userid
where a.userid = @userid and b.blocker_userid is null
```

Answer (score -1):

Using single query

```
select a.friend_name from table A as b, Table B as b where friend_id not In(blocker_userid) where userid = 3
```