# MySQL: Boolean query returning true if user has not set dnd or if user has set dnd given ID must be a friend

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I've these simple tables:

```
1. USER_DND
╔════════╦══════╗
║ UserID ║ DnD  ║
╠════════╬══════╣
╚════════╩══════╝

2. USER_FRIEND
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID ║ FriendID ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

`USER_DND`: It contains IDs of users and their do not disturb (Dnd) flag. `UserID` is integer and is primary key. `DnD` is boolean.

`USER_FRIEND`: It contains IDs of friends of users. `UserID` and `FriendID` both are integer.

**Problem:**

For given `UserID` and `FriendID` I want to write a *single* query returning boolean (`SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS`) that returns *true* in either of case:

If given UserID has `DnD` set false in `USER_DND`

OR

If given UserID has `DnD` set true in `USER_DND` and given FriendID exists in `USER_FRIEND` for that `UserID`

**Additional:**

These two are tables with large number of rows. Query need to be really fast. So I don't prefer using [`OR` in where clause of query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515133/1911652) or [query having subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31389660/1911652). Both has severe performance penalties.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the second condition, it doesn't make much sense. `FriendID` exists only in `USER_FRIEND` , so how can it not?

Comment: What does your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` look like for these? The key to performance is indexes.

Comment: @sagi: Question updated to make it more clear. Please check now. Thanks.

Comment: @tadman: This is translated from big tables having too many columns and indices for the sake of presenting issue on SO. As I stated USER_DND has primary key so that itself is index and in USER_FRIEND UserID is indexed.

Comment: Do you have an index on both `UserId, FriendID`? That's super important when doing a `JOIN`. This is why adding the schema of your tables, even a representative version, is very important and diagrams don't help all that much.

Comment: @tadman: Yes exactly I do have index on both UserId, FriendID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ud.dnd = 'FALSE' THEN 'TRUE'
                WHEN uf.FriendID = YourGivenFriendID THEN 'TRUE'
                ELSE 'FALSE'
           END) as user_ind
FROM USER_DND ud
LEFT JOIN USER_FRIEND uf
 ON(ud.userID = uf.userID)
WHERE uf.userID = YourGivenID
```

I assumed each user can have multiple friends, therefore the `MAX()` , if its 1-1 , you can remove the `MAX()`

Comment: Superb solution :)